# Html, CSS Switch button

Tags: html, css

I found a very nice CSS buttons creator http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/.
I created a switch button I know I need to execute two JS codes. Different for switch on and different for switch off. Lets say alert("on") when on and alert("off) when off. 
Can you please help me with that? Here is the html and css code

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
<div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
</label>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
    .onoffswitch {
      position: relative;
      width: 82px;
      -webkit-user-select:none;
      -moz-user-select:none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
      display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
      display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
      border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner {
      width: 200%;
      margin-left: -100%;
      -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
      -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
      -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
      transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    float: left; width: 50%; height: 24px; padding: 0; line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 18px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:before {
      content: "on";
      padding-left: 14px;
      background-color: #2FFF3D;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
      content: "off";
      padding-right: 14px;
      background-color: #ADADAD;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch {
      width: 28px; margin: 0px;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 5px;
      position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 50px;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
      right: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Attach a `change` event to `#myonoffswitch` and check `this.checked`.

Comment: I would avoid using a function name of `alert` as that will override the `window.alert`

Comment: Fair point @MrLister, that was not my immediate assumption, but on reflection I would agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple JQuery option [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm45k/)

```
$('#myonoffswitch').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         alert("ON")   
    } else {
         alert("OFF")   
    }
});
```

---

You could also do something like this if you wanted the function to run after the animation is complete [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm45k/1/)

```
$('#myonoffswitch').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert("ON")
            }, 334); 
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert("OFF")
            }, 334);  
        }
});
```

Comment: is it possible to make a 3-way switch like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) as 3rror404 has purposed.

But if you want pure Javascript you could do something like this

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" onchange="changeSwitch()" checked>
```

JS

```
function changeSwitch() {
     var isChecked = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked;
     if(isChecked) {
         //do what ever you need here when checked
         alert('ON')
     }
    else {
        //do what ever you need when not checked
        alert('OFF');
    }
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/josephs8/Q9AE7/)

Comment: is it possible to make a 3-way switch like this ?